# How to add additional validators in ngOnInit method?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular component i am adding some validators to the form in the constructor. However i want to add additional validators in my ngOnit method . how can i achieve this ?

```
   export class ResetPasswordComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private forgotPasswordService: ForgotPasswordService,
        private configService: ConfigService,
        private usersService: UsersService
      ) {
        this.blacklistedPasswords = this.configService.config.blacklistedPasswords;

        this.formGroup = this.fb.group(
          {
            password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
            confirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]]
          },
          {
            validator: Validators.compose([
              passwordStrengthValidator('password', 'confirmPassword'),
              blacklistedPasswordValidator(
                'password',
                'confirmPassword',
                this.blacklistedPasswords
              )
            ])
          }
        );
      }


ngOnInit() {

}
    }
```

how can i append another validator to the components ngOnInit method ?
for example i want to add a validator matchingValidator('password', 'confirmPassword') similar like that of passwordStrengthValidator & blacklistedPasswordValidator. How can i achieve it ?

I am a new bie to angular thank you so much

Comment: you want to create custom validator for password?

Comment: i have created a validator named matchingValidator and i want to append that validator to the list of  passwordStrengthValidator and blacklistedPasswordValidator , but in the ngOnInit method because i fetch some object and pass it to my matchingValidator .

Comment: i can't getting your point can you add some code what you trying?

Comment: I think you might be able to use the setValidators method. Something like  this.yourFormGroup.setValidators(matchingValidator);

Comment: what i was trying to achieve was adding new validators in the ngonit method with out loosing previous validators added to the form in the constructor method. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can append new validator like that:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.formGroup.setValidators(Validators.compose([this.formGroup.validator, matchingValidator('password', 'confirmPassword')]));
}
```

You need to pass all existing validators here because **setValidators** clears all existing validators and then adds what you pass. Hope that helps.